# How can i install the latest Ubuntu and delete Cent OS?

Tags: server, ssh, kvm-virtualization, vnc, putty

So I'm renting a server running on Cent OS 6.10 (Final).

And I need it to be running on Ubuntu instead of Cent OS.

The support of the renting company gave me the credentials for **VNC (KVM)** connection.

But I already have ssh connection through **PUTTY** so I don't even need logically I don't even need the **VNC** connection to do what I need to do.

I have searched for ways to do it through terminal, but non of them seem right and safe.

I've asked the renting company to do it and they replied with "unfortunately unable to install Ubuntu, as drivers are missing for your device for the install. The OS cannot detect a NIC during the install. If you could provide drivers, we can attempt the install again. Alternatively, we can try to set up a KVM for you and attach an ISO provided by yourself, and you could try a manual install."

Does anyone know how I can install Ubuntu instead of **Cent OS** ?

Comment: Ask the renting company to do it.

Comment: This is the funniest comment I've ever seen on this website haha. But jokes aside when I've asked them to do it they replied with "unfortunately unable to install Ubuntu, as drivers are missing for your device for the install. The OS cannot detect a NIC during the install. If you could provide drivers, we can attempt the install again. Alternatively, we can try to set up a KVM for you and attach an ISO provided by yourself, and you could try a manual install."

Comment: This is important information. Please add all this to the question above. Use the edit button below the question.

Comment: Did they tell you to use Virtual Machine Manager (VMM) to access the KVM?

Comment: Take the "we can try to set up a KVM for you and attach an ISO provided by yourself"-offer. Send them the Ubuntu iso you need and go through Ubuntu installer with the remote KVM.

Comment: @user68186 No They told me to use VNC.

Comment: Choose a different company to rent from that does support Ubuntu. If you are paying them, then you should not be required to provide your own support to install a common, popular OS.

Comment: I agree with @SimonSudler. The renting company should give you instructions on how to connect to the KVM. Once you do, you should see the Ubuntu installation screen. Install Ubuntu using the whole virtual disk. When finished, call the company to disconnect the ISO and reboot the VM.

Comment: Exactly what is the physical hardware?

Answer (score 0):

It's a while back since I last did something like that. Back then I wanted to run my servers with Gentoo instead of $anyotherlinux and this is roughly how I did it:

```
FOLLOWING THIS YOU MAY BREAK THE SYSTEM, BE CAUTIOUS AND PROCEED ON YOUR OWN RISK!
```

- Removed the swap partition and created an ext4 partition in its place
- Bootstrapped a basic linux with sshd to the former swap partition and reconfigured grub to boot from that partition
- Reboot from the intermediate linux
- Repartition the rest of the disk
- Mount all partitions in the desired layout (`/`, `/boot`, `/tmp`, `/var`, `/etc`)
- Bootstrap my target linux distribution into the newly created partitions and install sshd
- Reconfigure grub to boot from the newly created linux system and reboot
- Remove the intermediate linux partition and re-create a swap partition in its place.

Having VNC at hand is very helpful in this process in case you need to change the grub entry or even forgot to install sshd on some point.

Some hosters provide their customers with rescue-systems which are basically live-images to boot the system from. Using that would spare you the hassle of going through a intermediate linux in your swap partition.